# Найти первую/вторую валюту и число в сообщении пользователя, заданном списком

Tags: python, списки

```
messageFromUser = ['btc', 'в', 'usd'] #сообщение от пользователя
vals = ['btc', 'usd', 'rub', 'uah'] #Список с валютами
```

Нужно проверить есть ли в сообщении от пользователя 2 элемента списка с валютами и записать их в переменные:

- `val1` - Первая валюта, которую напишет пользователь.
- `num` - Изначально равно 1. Если в сообщении от пользователя после первой валюты идёт какое-то число, то оно приравнивается переменной `num`.
- `val2` - Вторая валюта, которую напишет пользователь.

Comment: Задание понятно. С чем возникли сложности?

Comment: А элементы будут идти всегда в такой последовательности: валюта- цифра-валюта, или может быть другая последовательность?

Answer (score 1):

Проверить есть ли в списке элементы другого списка можно простым пересечением -
 пробежаться по каждому списку вручную, но можно и пересечь их в виде сетов, что будет проще:

```
ans = list(set(messageFromUser)&set(vals))
```

После этого содержимое `ans` будет выглядеть так:

```
['btc', 'usd']
```

И легко можно достать из этого списка первый и второй элементы, а также проверить, содержит ли список введенных пользователем значений после первого элемента число, которое и будет являться `num`:

```
val1 = ans[0]
val2 = ans[1]
if (messageFromUser.index(val1)>messageFromUser.index(val2)):
    # Возможно элементы в листе поменяют свое положение в сете
    # Так что нужна данная проверка, 
    # Которая поставит каждую переменную на свое место
    tmp = val2
    val2 = val1
    val1 = tmp
try:
    num = int(messageFromUser[messageFromUser.index(val1) + 1])
except ValueError:
    # Какое-либо действие, если числа после val1 не содержится
```

Comment: `set()` не сохраняет порядок, поэтому результат может быть неверным у вас.

Comment: @jfs Да, действительно, спасибо.

Comment: можно так: `a, b = set(L) & set(vals); if L.index(a) > L.index(b): a, b = b, a`